# python: splitting strings where numbers and letters meet (1234abcd-->1234, abcd)

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have a string composed of numbers and letters: `string = 'this1234is5678it'`, and I would like the `string.split()` output to give me a list like `['this', '1234', 'is', '5678', 'it']`, splitting at where numbers and letter meet. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Regex for this.

```
import re
s = 'this1234is5678it'
re.split('(\d+)',s)
```

Running example http://ideone.com/JsSScE

Outputs `['this', '1234', 'is', '5678', 'it']`

**Update**

Steve Rumbalski mentioned in the comment the importance of the parenthesis in the regex. He quotes from the documentation:

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all
>   groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting
>   list." Without the parenthesis the result would be ['this', 'is',
>   'it'].

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the parenthesis in the regex are important here.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split): "If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list."  Without the parenthesis the result would be `['this', 'is', 'it']`.